# Lazily Read Stream of Bytes from File in Java 8

Tags: file-io, java-8, binaryfiles

So Java 8 introduces a lot of lazily loaded Streams, including one for reading lines from a text file using a particular character encoding.

But after doing a LOT of reading I've determined that there is no out of the box method to lazily read chunks of bytes from file, and I'm a bit confused as to why this is the case. This is a pretty common use-case, so there must be a good reason for it to not have been included, right?

My best solution to this seems to be a custom implementation of a Spliterator to read byte chunks using some guidance from this post:
https://www.airpair.com/java/posts/parallel-processing-of-io-based-data-with-java-streams

But I would love to know why Java 8 doesn't have this feature out of the box?

Comment: What abstraction are you thinking about exactly? `Stream<Byte>` would be very expensive.

Comment: I'd really just like a stream that lets me read a binary file... Why would Stream<Byte> be so expensive?

Comment: If you want a “lazily loaded stream”, you can use the good old `FileInputStream` as it won’t load any data unless you request it via a `read` call. That’s all about what “lazy” means. You may also use a `FileChannel` as it fulfills the definition as well, even when it isn’t name “stream”. If you have an actual problem that these streams can’t solve, ask a more specific question.

Comment: I suppose I didn't word my original question as well as I should have. I would like to be able to read in a binary file and apply all the nice functional abstractions to it that were introduced into java 8, and then write it back to a file. I would like to do this without all the extra ugliness that java seems to be forcing one me. It seems like I should be able to have a Stream from a binary file that I apply some arbitrary encoding to, alter it in some interesting way, and then stream it back to another file, all in just a few short lines.

Comment: what is "lazily" got to do with it? Also the Collections.stream() in Java8, is that the same as FileInput"Stream"? I didn't think so but somehow you are confusing me :)